# Making global variable url

Tags: web-services, automated-tests, global-variables, katalon-studio

happy new year ! 
I have a question, can I make global variable urls in Katalon Studio ? I had imported swagger file into katalon, but url is not correct.

imported swagger looks like that: http://www.example.com/v1/statement/${accountId}?startDate=&endDate=&inEquivalent= , is it possible to define that www.example.com should be www.google.com, so I don't need to change every requests url by myself ?

**Edit:** I tried to make a global variable in the profile, for example name=example type=string value=google.com, but when I try to send request, it shows 502 Bad Gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `GlobalVariable.example=google.com`, and let us say your imported swagger is defined as a string

```
String swagg = "http://www.example.com/v1/statement/${accountId}?startDate=&endDate=&inEquivalent="
```

you can replace the "www.example.com" part with the global variable in the script like this:

```
String swagg2 = "http://${GlobalVariable.example}/v1/statement/${accountId}?startDate=&endDate=&inEquivalent="
```